# Open wpf window from other project

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, .net-assembly

I have two separate project for example project1 and project2. Well i have a window1 in the project1 so how can i show this window1 from project2.

Comment: Are your projects part of the same solution or are they seperate executables

Comment: Yes they both are WPF project and both are in the same solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to add a project reference to the project you want to call the other project from. You can then do something like this. I have 2 different Namespaces but something like this should work.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        WpfApplication2.MainWindow newForm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            newForm = new WpfApplication2.MainWindow();

            newForm.Show();  // or newForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well when using a wpf application to launch an XNA game.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to add Project 1 reference to Project 2 project and then call window1 as you're used to do (Don't forget before calling : you need `using Project1;` where you want to call window1 so the intellisense would find it easly for you)

Comment: yes i have added the Project1 reference to Project2 but i am getting NullReferenceException                                                
          object o = (Window)System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("Project1").CreateInstance("MainWindow");
          Window s = (Window)o;
          s.Show();

Comment: @user1399377 you do not need to be using System.Reflection if you have a reference to the Project.

Comment: what's the purpose of using System.Reflection instead of this simple way ?